# How to install Bumblebee-UI (GUI) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am quite interested in installing Bumblebee-UI in Ubuntu 12.04 after seeing this video on youtube. [Link to video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JdJ6tGCH44)

Has anyone been able to install it successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Install Git:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install git
  ```
- Make a directory for git:

  ```
  mkdir git
  cd git
  ```
- Check out the repository:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
  cd bumblebee-ui
  sudo ./INSTALL
  ```
- Go to `Startup Applications` and add `/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-indicator`.

Comment: This won't work out of the box, because it doesn't follow python best practices for installation.

Comment: The repository no longer exists, so unfortunately this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but the answer is clear and simple

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui/blob/master/README#L27

Comment: Have you done it successfully?