# Can't type my username and password, random freeze at login

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

My netbook runs a dual OS(Windows7 & Ubuntu 12.04). After Ubuntu login screen appears, that’s it, it gets hanged, can't even move my cursor nor type my user name.

I had to turn off my system and boot again. Still its not sure that it won't freeze out at login screen again, but this is the temporary solution I have to get into Ubuntu.

This freezing at login screen doesn't happen every time, it happens randomly. It seems like I had to enter into Ubuntu purely based on my luck, which is quite irritating. I found many other types of login problem in Ubuntu when I googled, which were quite different from my case. So any1 kindly help me out.

Comment: Which laptop is it?
and what are the specs`?

Comment: Can you do Ctrl-Alt-F1 to switch to a text console?

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes Asus 1225b netbook, 4GB ram, 320GB HDD, AMD  64-bit, E450 processor with 1.66GHz speed.

Comment: @January ctrl+alt+F1 doesn't solve my problem. There is no response when I do ctrl+alt+F1.

Comment: That wasn't a solution, I just wanted to know whether the whole system hangs or it is just the X windows. Try to look at /var/log/messages. Look at last messages from the last regular boots (each line is preceded by a data). Post it here.

Comment: @January pasted from syslog file. check if these r right.      Sep  4 15:27:42 ubuntu kernel: [ 1506.784373] ieee80211 phy0: AMPDU status: BA Timeout, seq 3436, in_transit 1
Sep  4 15:27:42 ubuntu kernel: [ 1506.784395] ieee80211 phy0: AMPDU status: BA Timeout, seq 3437, in_transit 0
Sep  4 15:27:55 ubuntu kernel: [ 1520.312540] ieee80211 phy0: AMPDU status: BA Timeout, seq 3577, in_transit 0
Sep  4 15:29:33 ubuntu rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="865" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed

Comment: Where is it? Can't find the link.

Comment: it just shows http://www.rsyslog.com in the original file. where you looking for these lines  which i have pasted in my prev msg ?

Comment: OK, just to get this straight. This were the only lines that you found in /var/log/syslog? Let's look into /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/dmesg, then. Please use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ instead of pasting the lines directly in the comments. Also, make sure that you collect these files right after the freeze. Check the exact date / hour on the syslog lines.

Comment: @January These were not the only lines. there were a lot. i couldn't paste more. thanks for the paste.ubuntu.com,i didn't know about it before. BTW, when u say the files right after the freeze, i can only take them after i turn off my system and again login. Is tat how u wanna me take those files?

Comment: What we need are any log messages from just before the freeze. So if your computer froze at 15:32, and you wait a few minutes and reboot it at 15:40, then the relevant lines from log files should have a 15:32 timestamp.

Comment: @January message from syslog http://paste.ubuntu.com/1190328/ message from kern.log http://paste.ubuntu.com/1190331/ BTW I COULDN'T FIND 9:05AM TIME STAMP IN KERN.LOG FILE.       message from dmesg http://paste.ubuntu.com/1190336/

Comment: @January waiting for ur reply ... !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I cannot help you. However, I will start a bounty in your name, maybe someone else would see what is going on.

Comment: Hi, does your pc has nvidia? I have seen similar problems in a friend's laptop. EDIT: I just noticed also Kacper's answer, could be the case.

Comment: @user81022 my netbook has AMD radeon HD 6320

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> did not work, neither did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. A complete freeze.

What seemed to work for me though was a reboot in the *recovery mode* which runs **Unity 2D instead of 3D**. I figured that it must have been due to the graphic card drivers. 
Since I was using GeForce ​GT ​540M, I installed **Ironhide**:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/ironhide
apt-get update
apt-get install ironhide
```

Then when configuring ironhide (`ironhide-configure`), I chose the last configuration from the bottom (apparently the most recent), for 12.04 LTS, and after reboot, it worked just as it used to, without any freezes.

Try it out yourself!

Comment: Kacper, have you seen this? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/134594/how-to-install-bumblebee-ui-gui-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @Kacper could the command apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/ironhide,  be used for amd radeon 6320 graphics card or do i have to modify the command ?

Comment: @rakesh: was that answer helpful in your case? Did you get to solve your problem?

Comment: @January i haven't tried this.Because, before i try, i want to know  if this first command is applicable to my PC, because my pc uses a AMD radeon. when i googled, i found out that these commands are used by those who have  Nvidia graphics card. So i am little afraid if this could corrupt my current drivers. if some1 can assure me  that this command can be used to pc's with AMD radeon graphics card,then i can go ahead with this solution. Thats why i have raised a question to kacper.

Comment: Ok, I was just asking "in any case" -- the bounty is due.

Comment: i tried kacper's solution. i think apt-get install ironhide didn't happen succesfully due to which,it says ironhide-configuration command not found. check the reports which came on the command line while trying his solution http://paste.ubuntu.com/1210874/

Comment: I'm afraid Ironhide would not help in you case. You might want to give a try to new ATI Catalyst Drivers. There is plenty of information on how to properly install them on Ubuntu, e.g. here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalysat-video-drivers)

Answer (score -1):

You can try login via command-line:
Type **ctrl+alt+F1** at boot to switch to command-line login.
Then your user name and password will be asked.
Now you should have logged in successfully.
If you have some problems regarding this visit this [link.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1822622&seqNum=2)

Comment: How about reading the discussion? The user reports that when the computer is hanging (which does not occur *always*), Ctrl-Alt-F1 does not work.

Comment: @January I am talking about boot screen or splash screen!

Comment: yes, nonetheless the user stated clearly that "There is no response when I do ctrl+alt+F1."

Comment: @PranitBauva I don't get a command-line login  when i press ctrl alt f1 during boot. It directly proceeds to the ubuntu login screen.