# Installing nVidia driver on 13.04 64bit Macbook pro 7,1

Tags: nvidia, macbook

I've just installed 13.04 64bit on my Macbook pro 7,1 (using the whole disk instead of dual boot). But after installing the nVidia driver my notebook just failed to boot. Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: It can't boot, or it boots with a black screen?

Comment: Solution is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/613573/134848

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to Lijunda, and was getting a black screen.

I booted using recovery mode and purged the nivida drivers. After a reboot everything works fine.