# Installation of Ubuntu 15.04 on MacBookPro7,1 with proper NVIDIA drivers

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, macbook-pro

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a MacBookPro7,1, and have a few questions.

I successfully installed Ubuntu previously, but it failed to boot eventually; there was a purple screen with a black bar in the middle. I had to boot into OS X and nuke the partition via Disk Utility.

I have rEFInd installed.

I figured this was a problem with the graphics drivers, as Linux Mint (an Ubuntu-based distro) had MAJOR problems with graphics. The graphics card is an NVIDIA (I hate NVIDIA ;p) GeForce 320M. Upon installing the drivers on my current EFI install of Ubuntu, I experienced serious problems similar to the ones described here: http://korrekt.org/page/Note:How_to_install_%28K%29Ubuntu_14.04_on_Macbook_7,1

My question is, how do I get Ubuntu running with the proper NVIDIA drivers? I know how to get Wi-Fi working, but not full graphics support. According to the guide linked earlier, I need to get a Ubuntu install running in BIOS mode, but how do I do that? I don't understand the guide.

I'm willing to get technical with this; I need to get away from OS X Yosemite, it runs badly on my hardware.

Comment: In http://askubuntu.com/questions/616630/ubuntu-mate-brightness-keys-not-working-on-macbookpro7-1-with-nvidia-driver-eve you wrote *I'm using a MacBookPro7,1 (13-inch Mid-2010) with the NVIDIA drivers installed.*

Comment: @karel I used a GRUB script to allow me to use the NVIDIA drivers in EFI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple GRUB script as detailed here: [Proprietary NVidia drivers with EFI on Mac, to prevent overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573#613573) should solve the problem.