# Ubuntu MATE brightness keys not working on MacBookPro7,1 with NVIDIA driver, even after fix

Tags: nvidia, xorg, brightness, macbook-pro

I tried the fix detailed in the first answer for this question: [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver)

The second answer caused a failed boot and I had to fix it via Recovery.

The first answer (the one used now) has no effect. It doesn't cause Xorg to fail to start, but it does nothing.

How do I fix my brightness keys? I'm using a MacBookPro7,1 (13-inch Mid-2010) with the NVIDIA drivers installed.

Comment: Did you try  the open source Nouveau driver That Cerin mentioned in his comment?

Comment: @ElderGeek Nouveau works, but has issues which I installed the NVIDIA driver to avoid (mainly performance issues). Hell, Nouveau broke the entire OS when I tried out Linux Mint.

Comment: Well, I can't comment on Mint. I know that it's also based on Debian, but I wouldn't expect the same results from 2 different distros. Sorry about the performance, but until NVIDIA opens up their code, the Ubuntu developers can't fix it. It looks like for the moment you may have to choose between the performance you are getting from the NVIDIA driver and the brightness keys. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the following url:

http://cosmicb.no/2014/05/18/nvidia-brightness-control-fix/

Briefly, what you have to do is to compile the nvidiadl driver and tell grub that the brightness will be handled using acpi by passing the  acpi_backlight=vendor argumentto the kernel.