# 19.10: MacPro 5.1 and multiple NVIDIA cards

Tags: nvidia, uefi, 19.10, mac

I want to get MacPro 5.1 working with my two NVIDIA 1080 Ti cards. I have the original 9500GT installed as well, so i was able to install Ubuntu and NVIDIA drivers. I get a picture out from 9500GT but not from the 1080 Ti cards. Nvidia X server window is totally empty. nvidia-smi shows both cards, as shown below, so i think the problem shouldn't be the drivers.

```
MacPro:/$ nvidia-smi
Tue Apr  7 11:08:41 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   34C    P5    20W / 280W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P5    27W / 280W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I noticed [MacBook Pro, EFI and Nvidia setpci IDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716565/macbook-pro-efi-and-nvidia-setpci-ids) but since NVIDIA recognize cards, perhaps this should't be the problem?

How may I troubleshoot this and get video from the 1080 Ti cards?

Edit.1

I'm runing GDM Ubuntu 19.10. I updated latest 440 drivers and pulled 9500GT card out. I have 2x30in monitors attached in the second 1080ti. When i boot without 9500, I dont get image anymore. When login screen should come, i see that second monitor activates but lost connection again. I have tried add nomodeset in then grub as in some tutorials ask but no help. Only thing what changed when I pulled 9500 out, nvidia-smi gives some running process now.

```
Tue Apr  7 12:42:13 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   34C    P8    16W / 280W |     16MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P8    17W / 280W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1218      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             9MiB |
|    0      1295      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit.2

It seems that sudo get-edid | parse-edid gets monitor info (4k monitor)

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "U32J59x"
        ModelName "U32J59x"
        VendorName "SAM"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 1 of 2019
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 700 390
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "true"
        Horizsync 30-135
        VertRefresh 24-75
        # Maximum pixel clock is 600MHz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 97)
#DOUBLE WARNING: It's your first mode, too, so this may actually be important.
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 95)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 96)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 93)
#WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 94)
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 0" 594.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 2" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 4" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 5" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 6" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 7" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 8" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 9" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 10" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 11" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 12" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 1"
EndSection
```

Edit3.

I got it work! Stupid thing and amateur mistake, I had to change cables to second 1080ti. Now both monitors get 4k resolution!

Comment: What happens if you shut down, remove the original 9500GT card , and boot up with just the Ti cards connected to the monitor? And, which version of 19.10 are you running? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]