# Ubuntu 14.04 black screen afters installing prorpietary nvidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have just reinstalled the Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop due to upgrading to an SSD and now I am experiencing an issue with nvidia drivers. When I install a proprietary driver after a reboot the systel launches (i can hear sound) but the screen is black. I have tried several guides and no luck so far.

I have tried installing both availiable drivers from nvidia:
nvidia-352
nvidia-352-updates

The solution proposed it the following answer didn't help:
[Proprietary NVidia drivers with EFI on Mac, to prevent overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573#613573)

Laptop ASUS K501LB
VGA GeForce 940M

**UPDATE:** The nvidia-352 driver is working fine, but only after I have reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04. This time I used **14.04.3** and the problems were when I was using **14.04.4**.

**P.S.** Should I report this as a bug to Ubuntu developers?

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed a bugged driver. I know on some GPU models, there are 3 to four different proprietary drivers to install. Which results in the black screen of Death. Similar to the black screen of death on Windows where a buggy windows update or an infection "deletes" access to the desktop.

From Nixie Pixel on YouTube, she was able to do a work around. This video is from a while ago and she is using 12.04, however, it should work for 14.04.

[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmZYzaxR_k)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. After following the instructions from that video I have managed to get an image of the login screen, but it is in a very low resolution and I can't log in - when I enter my password I am still ending up seeing the login screen and asked to enter the password to log in.