# How to Install Single Boot Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacbookAir3,1?

Tags: 18.04, bios, macbook-air, csm

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 as the single OS on a MacbookAir3,1. In addition, I'd like to use the proprietary graphics drivers, but there are some known issues with that. I attempted to run the install while booted from USB drive, but the graphics issue seems to be preventing the thumdrive from booting all the way.

[The guide I'm following](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209602) (although for an older version) suggests that the process is much easier when installing from an optical disc than with a thumb drive. Will it work from a DVD with Ubuntu 18.04? Is a specific Kernel version required for best results?

Comment: I don't think Nvidia driver is an issue now.

Comment: What else might be the cause of the failed boot, then?

Comment: How did you prepare the USB?

Comment: I burned it to usb using Etcher, on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this question by following the steps outlined in the answer to this related question: [Proprietary NVidia drivers with EFI on Mac, to prevent overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573)

As it says there, essentially what's needed is to "create a GRUB script for setting the PCI-E registers during boot"