# MacBook Pro w/ Ubuntu Blank Screen Boot-Up

Tags: 18.04, graphics, macbook, support

I have two MacBooks. One installed Ubuntu 18.04 flawlessly. The other would hang on the Splash Screen for the intial install. So in the grub menu, I pressed 'e' and typed in nomodeset where applicable. That did the trick, and I was able to install Ubuntu. Then I updated the graphics to NVIDIA, rebooted, and now I'm getting a blank screen on boot-up. If I press option + command + r, I'm able to get to the grub menu again (not from the boot USB), and if I press e, I see that nomodeset is already there. I don't understand what to do at this point.

I also tried to start completely over, and press option + power to boot to USB, and my USB drive won't show up in the menu! I tried different USB drives, and same result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573#613573). If I'm installing Ubuntu, then I have to press 'e' and add 'nomodeset' to the grub menu. After it's installed, I have to follow the directions in the link in order to install proper NVIDIA drivers. I actually have LUbuntu installed now, which doesn't require the 'nomodeset' method at all. But I still need to follow the directions to get the proper NVIDIA driver.

I still don't actually know how to get out of the black screen thing apart from reinstalling the OS. Also, I figured out how to get the USB to be detected on boot. I press Control + Option + R + P, then press the power button, and continue holding everything except the power button. The system start-up noise and gray screen will show, and then turn black, and will make the noise and gray screen again as long as I'm holding the key combos. I let it reboot like this about 3-4 times, then shut down. Then I press Option + Power, and see if the USB shows. If it doesn't I try that method again. Eventually, it shows up and I can reinstall the OS.