# NVIDIA driver problems on Macbook Pro mid 2010

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, macbook-pro

I´ve just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Macbook Pro, and from the outset I had trouble with system stability. Eventually I narrowed the problem down to the nvidia drivers (card is an MCP89 Geforce G320). In software and updates I set the driver to proprietory and re-booted.

On reboot the graphics are completely lost, all black. I need some stepwise help to dig myself out and get the drivers to work properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

maybe that's the well known "EFI with proprietary Nvidia drivers enabled" related problem. You should try this answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/613573/581590 which solved my problem (but it was a long time ago).

Hope that helps.