# Safe to install Nvidia drivers with my setup?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with Optirun/Primusrun installed, and I'm experiencing a lot of Xorg crashes (Both in Unity and Gnome 3.8), and I want to install the Nvidia drivers, as I'm currently using the standard Intel drivers.

Is it safe for me to install the nvidia drivers through their installer? or is it better to install them through apt-get?

And what do I do if it fails to boot?

**Extra info:**

GPU: Intel/Nvidia Geforce 520MX (Optimus Card)

Comment: I think you can install them, but it won't make any positive difference. Your Intel card is always going to be the device your computer uses to put things on the screen. That's just how Optimus works. I'd be interested to hear from somebody with an Optimus setup though.

Comment: I have read somewhere that the new driver, should take over instead of the Intel drivers.

Comment: @oli I wouldn't be so sure about that. 

dasmikko: Xorg should practically never crash. If it is crashing then a new driver might be just the solution. I would try the apt-get package first and if that doesn't work then go get the nvidia driver.

Comment: @krowe Are you saying that I should update my intel drivers, or just install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: You want the nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bumblebee driver.

Here is how to install bumblebee:

Quoting from [Bumblebee on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

> You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.
>
> If on 12.04.3, replace `linux-headers-generic` with
>   `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`.
>
> 1. (not needed for 13.10 Saucy and newer)
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
>    ```
> 2. Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories (for bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively).
> 3. ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 4. Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
>    ```
> 5. Reboot

---

Now you have to install Bumblebee GUI to manage apps to be opened using nVidia. Here is the instructions from [How to install Bumblebee-UI (GUI) in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134594/how-to-install-bumblebee-ui-gui-in-ubuntu-12-04)

> - Install Git:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt-get install git
>   ```
> - Make a directory for git:
>
>   ```
>   mkdir git
>   cd git
>   ```
> - Check out the repository:
>
>   ```
>   git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
>   cd bumblebee-ui
>   sudo ./INSTALL
>   ```
> - Go to `Startup Applications` and add `/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-indicator`

Now reboot again.